# App engine NDB: how to access verbose_name of a property

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

suppose I have this code:

```
class A(ndb.Model):
    prop = ndb.StringProperty(verbose_name="Something")

m = A()
m.prop = "a string value"
```

Now of course if I print m.prop, it will output "a string value" while in fact it's a StringProperty instance. So verbose_name can't be accessed the "normal" way, i.e `m.prop._verbose_name`.
I read the code and found a way to access it: `m._properties["prop"]._verbose_name`, it works, but it looks hacky o_o.
So tell me, is there another way to do it?
Note: I'm talking about the NDB API, not the old one

Comment: Doesn't seem very hacky to me, if you actually need to inspect the name during usage rather than declaration.

Answer (score 8):

Use a class attribute: `A.prop._verbose_name`. Or `m.__class__.prop._verbose_name`.